# Regex Inconsistency in my browser and my friends browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

So my friend and I are trying to solve a specific problem in regex where we have this code.

```js
const x = '/order/0d75f8a6-165f-427a-820f-259afbddf9d9/product/235768d7-a1ca-4424-a3f8-fa5ddab90ceb'
const r = x.match(/\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*/g)
```

In my computer the result comes out as

```
["/order/0d75f8a6-165f-427a-820f-259afbddf9d9", "/product/235768d7-a1ca-4424-a3f8-fa5ddab90ceb"]
```

but for some reason my friends computer comes out as

```
null
```

We have the same version of chrome and I even tried it in Nodejs, Js Fiddle, Chrome console but the results in both of our computer didnt change.... I am not sure why...

Comment: My computer does the same thing your computer does. Not sure how your friend's computer gets `null`.

Comment: The statement “* the results in both of our computer are the same*” directly contradicts your earlier statement that your results in fact differ. Can you edit your question to clarify what the problem is exactly? Can you also share pertinent environment information (browser version, OS, etc.)?

Comment: I've edited that part... what I mean was it didn't change no matter where we go.. his answer remains the same and my answer remains the same too.

Comment: I have a chrome Version 89.0.4389.72 (Official Build) (64-bit) and nodejs 12.. we have the same version also..

Comment: this sounds like a copy-paste problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you using glip to send this snippet? if it is the "*" is being treated as a font style on glip chat

Comment: apparently you are right... thank you so much.